# Change Public or Private Chatter Group to Unlisted

Tags: apex, collaborationgroup

Is there any way to do this with the IDE, or any sort of workaround? It looks unlikely, but I just want to make sure before I create a new unlisted group and migrate the group contents to it.

I ran the following Apex in an Execute Anonymous command and it threw a DMLException that pretty much resoundingly says "we don't want this behavior to be possible."

Exception:

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception
>   on row 0 with id 0F9G00000004lE9KAI; first error: INVALID_STATUS, You
>   can't make an existing group unlisted.: [CollaborationType]

Apex:

```
CollaborationGroup c = [SELECT CollaborationType,Id FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Id = '0F9G00000004lE9KAI'];
c.CollaborationType = 'Unlisted';
update c;
```

UI on "Group Settings" of the group:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not currently supported.

> You can convert unlisted groups to public or private groups, but not the other way around.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_unlisted_groups_overview.htm&language=en_US

If this is something that has to be done, you could create a new Unlisted version of the group and migrate all the Chatter discussions & memberships to the new group (and then delete the old one). Depending on the use of the group, you may have to audit references elsewhere (@ mentions of the group, any ID references for URLs, etc).